# Internal web scraper library

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a python web scraper library that isn't a user-made or external library

I've found beautifulsoup, selenium, and requests as user-made libraries for python web scraping

before I start working on this I would just like to know if I do not need to install a different library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no web scraper library in the Python standard library.

There are `http.client` and `html` and other modules, which could be building blocks for a web scraping library... but at that point you're just doing by hand what Beautiful Soup and Requests do, so there's no point, really.